# Sympy gives numerical numpy output in dtype object format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, casting, sympy

I am using the following piece of code to create symbolic Sympy expressions for the [spherical harmonics functions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#spherical-harmonics) Y_l^m (4-pi-normalized over the full sphere) and their theta derivatives and then want to evaluate them on some evenly spaced grid in theta and phi coordinates:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi, cos, sin
import sympy
from sympy import Ynm, simplify, diff, lambdify
from sympy.abc import n,m,theta,phi

resol = 2.5
dtheta_rad_ylm = -resol * pi/180.0
dphi_rad_ylm = resol * pi/180.0

thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm = np.arange(pi+dtheta_rad_ylm/2.0,dtheta_rad_ylm/2.0,dtheta_rad_ylm)
phiarr_rad_ylm = np.arange(0.0,2*pi,dphi_rad_ylm)
phi_grid_rad_ylm, theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm = np.meshgrid(phiarr_rad_ylm, thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm)

lmax = len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm)/2 - 1
nmax = (lmax+1)*(lmax+2)/2

ylms_symm_full = np.zeros((lmax+1, lmax+1, len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))
dylms_symm_full = np.zeros((lmax+1, lmax+1, len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))

for n in np.arange(0,lmax+1):
  for m in np.arange(0,n+1):
    print "generating resol %s, y_%d_%d" % (resol,n,m)

    ylm_symbolic = simplify(2 * sympy.sqrt(sympy.pi) * Ynm(n,m,theta,phi).expand(func=True))
    dylm_symbolic = simplify(diff(ylm_symbolic, theta))

    # activate and deactivate comments for second-question-related error
    # error appears later than the first-question-related error!
    ylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), sympy.N(ylm_symbolic), "numpy")
    dylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), sympy.N(dylm_symbolic), "numpy")
#    ylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), ylm_symbolic, "numpy")
#    dylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), dylm_symbolic, "numpy")

    # activate and deactivate comments for first-question-related error
    ylm_symm_full = np.asarray(ylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm), dtype=complex)
    dylm_symm_full = np.asarray(dylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm), dtype=complex)
#    ylm_symm_full = ylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm)
#    dylm_symm_full = dylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm)

    if n == 0 and m == 0:
      ylm_symm_full = np.tile(ylm_symm_full, (len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))
      dylm_symm_full = np.tile(dylm_symm_full, (len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))

    ylms_symm_full[n,m,:,:] = np.real(ylm_symm_full)
    dylms_symm_full[n,m,:,:] = np.real(dylm_symm_full)
```

There are several other packages providing the functionality of generating numeric Y_l^m without symbolic expressions, like [scipy.special.sph_harm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.sph_harm.html). However, it is crucial for me to get an "exact" derivative, i.e. not using any numerical differentiation method as e.g. finite differences ([np.gradient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)). Therefore after getting the symbolic formula for the Y_l^m and simplifying those "as much as possible", lambda functions are created using the numpy backend (to be able to do vectorized calculations) and those are then evaluated on the grid. Finally I only need the real part of the spherical harmonics (I know that I could also create real spherical harmonics with Znm instead of Ynm, but...).

Two questions:

1. Mostly, the numerical output is then given as a usual 2d-numpy array of dtype complex or np.complex128. In some cases however, Sympy generates the array having a dtype object, this affects particularly the high l spherical harmonics. Array entries are displayed as complex 1-tuples instead of just complex numbers. The problem however is that taking the real part on that array has no effect, resulting in an error, since it is broadcast into an array that has a real dtype. Is there any particular reason for this? I do not see any immediate one, since the output is not inhomogeneous. Any way to change this without having to cast it additionally to dtype complex using [np.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)? It just takes additional computation time, makes the program slightly more complicated, but more importantly confusing.
2. You may also have noted that I use sympy.N to evaluate the expression already before I create the lambda function. The reason is that the prefactors in front of the spherical harmonics are in some cases of long format and numpy, for whoever knows which reason, cannot compute the sqrt of that number. Note that this is not in general true (`np.sqrt(9L) = 3.0`), but in this case there's an error message stating that the *long object has no attribute sqrt*. I suppose this is also related to the lambda function generation. Is there any method to tell Sympy to give already the symbolic expression in float format every time? Or, better, to somehow modify the lambdify call?

The code block should be stand-alone and testable, if you want to check these issues. Just remove the sympy.N and the np.asarray expressions. The first question relates to the error appearing earlier. Y_l^m generation up to the lmax which here is 35 takes roughly 10-15 minutes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

**UPDATE:** Here are some minimal, complete and verifiable examples. For both please import the required packages:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi, cos, sin
import sympy
from sympy import Ynm, simplify, diff, lambdify
from sympy.abc import n,m,theta,phi
```

**Error #1:** object dtype problem at an = 31, m = 1:

```
# minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVe) #1
# error message:

#---> 43     dylms_symm_full[n,m,:,:] = np.real(dylm_symm_full)
#TypeError: can't convert complex to float

ylm_symbolic = simplify(2 * sympy.sqrt(sympy.pi) * Ynm(31,1,theta,phi).expand(func=True))
dylm_symbolic = simplify(diff(ylm_symbolic, theta))

ylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), ylm_symbolic, "numpy")
dylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), dylm_symbolic, "numpy")

ylm_symm_full = ylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm)
dylm_symm_full = dylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm)

ylms_symm_full = np.zeros((len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))
dylms_symm_full = np.zeros((len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))

ylms_symm_full[:,:] = np.real(ylm_symm_full)
dylms_symm_full[:,:] = np.real(dylm_symm_full)

print ylm_symm_full
print dylm_symm_full
```

**Error #2:** long sqrt attribute problem at n = 32, m = 29:

```
# minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVe) #2
# error message:

#---> 33     ylm_symm_full = np.asarray(ylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm), dtype=complex)
#/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <lambda>(_Dummy_4374, _Dummy_4375)
#AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

ylm_symbolic = simplify(2 * sympy.sqrt(sympy.pi) * Ynm(32,29,theta,phi).expand(func=True))
dylm_symbolic = simplify(diff(ylm_symbolic, theta))

ylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), ylm_symbolic, "numpy")
dylm_lambda = lambdify((theta,phi), dylm_symbolic, "numpy")

ylm_symm_full = np.asarray(ylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm), dtype=complex)
dylm_symm_full = np.asarray(dylm_lambda(theta_grid_rad_ylm_symm, phi_grid_rad_ylm), dtype=complex)

ylms_symm_full = np.zeros((len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))
dylms_symm_full = np.zeros((len(thetaarr_rad_ylm_symm), len(phiarr_rad_ylm)))

ylms_symm_full[:,:] = np.real(ylm_symm_full)
dylms_symm_full[:,:] = np.real(dylm_symm_full)

print ylm_symbolic                # the symbolic Y_32^29 expression
print type(175844649714253329810) # the number that causes the problem
```

Comment: I couldn't test your code, even with the suggested omissions.  You need to focus the example and question.

Comment: @hpaulj: I included your suggestions, MCVes are there now.

Answer (score 0):

The question of why your code produces an object array on occasion isn't something we can't easily answer without a MCVe - it can't just happen on occasion, it has to be reproducible.

However if the array is object, it might be easily converted to complex with

```
arr.astype(np.complex)
```

With a `copy=False` parameter you could apply it to all results without much computational cost.

```
arr.astype(np.complex, copy=False).real
```

The elements of the object version aren't tuples; they are scalar complex values, and just print that way.

```
In [187]: arr=np.random.rand(3)+np.random.rand(3)*1j
In [188]: arrO=arr.astype(object)
In [189]: arrO
Out[189]: 
array([(0.6129476673822528+0.09323924558124808j),
       (0.9540542895309456+0.81929476753951j),
       (0.8068967867200485+0.9494305517611881j)], dtype=object)
In [190]: type(arrO[0])
Out[190]: complex
In [191]: arr.real
Out[191]: array([ 0.61294767,  0.95405429,  0.80689679])
In [193]: arrO[0]
Out[193]: (0.6129476673822528+0.09323924558124808j)
In [194]: arrO.astype(np.complex).real
Out[194]: array([ 0.61294767,  0.95405429,  0.80689679])
```

Some math operations do 'bleed-through' to elements of an object array, but `real` is not one of them.  So as you note `np.real(arrO)` does not produce what you want.

---

Looking more at your code, including the stuff that scrolls off the screen I see you are using:

```
np.asarray(dylm_lambda(...), dtype=complex)
```

That's the same as my `astype(complex, copy=False)`.

For an already complex array the computational cost is minimal.  For an object array it has to make a new array, and the cost more substantial.  But if you can't figure out by `sympy` is creating the object array, you have to live with the cost.